# html5 display audio currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, audio, duration, html5-audio

I would like to display the current time of of an html 5 audio element and the duration of that element. I've been looking over the internet but can't find a functional script which allows me to display how long the audio files is and what the time currently is e.g. 1:35 / 3:20.

Any one got any ideas :)?

Comment: Try audio.currentTime gives anything? I not sure if it will work.

Comment: how would I add that it?

Comment: how would I add that in? <script type="text/javascript">audio.currentTime</script>?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<audio id="track" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg"
       ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
<span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').play();">Play</button>
```

This should work in Firefox and Chrome, for other browsers you'll probably need to add alternative encodings.

Comment: i am unable to bind `ontimeupdate` in my js.. how can i do that?

Comment: atharva johri just use a function in ontimeupdate and do your stuff in that function.

Comment: is there a way to make this code work for blob URL to play mp3?

Answer (score 31):

here is simple usage.  keep in mind html5 elements are still in the works so anything can change:

```
    audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

    //functions
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    audio.pause();

    //properties
    audio.currentSrc  
    audio.currentTime  
    audio.duration
```

here is the reference [HTML5 Audio](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#audio)

to get the currentTime while audio is playing you must attach the `timeupdate` event and update your current time within the callback function.

[simple tutorial audio/video html5 on dev.opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)

Comment: Don't you love how your answers not correct unless you write the code the OP wants?  Good answer.

Comment: i don't want to tinker with html5 until its official. too many browsers to debug lol =D thanks mate.

Comment: I'm not saying his answer is wrong, I just don't understand JS and html 5 audio is new to me so I didn't quite understand what to do with this :)

Comment: It takes awhile for someone to easily put all of these different components together. I know when I was starting out, showing just this wouldn't have helped me understand how the code can be written.

Answer (score 14):

robertc's version will work fine except for the fact that it does not turn the number of seconds you get from `math.floor()` into proper time values.

Here is my function called when `ontimeupdate` is called:

```
<audio id='audioTrack' ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);'>
  Audio tag not supported in this browser</audio>
<script>
function updateTrackTime(track){
  var currTimeDiv = document.getElementById('currentTime');
  var durationDiv = document.getElementById('duration');

  var currTime = Math.floor(track.currentTime).toString(); 
  var duration = Math.floor(track.duration).toString();

  currTimeDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(currTime);

  if (isNaN(duration)){
    durationDiv.innerHTML = '00:00';
  } 
  else{
    durationDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(duration);
  }
}
</script>
```

I modified `formatSecondsAsTime()` from something I found [here](http://codeaid.net/javascript/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds-%28javascript%29):

```
function formatSecondsAsTime(secs, format) {
  var hr  = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600))/60);
  var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) -  (min * 60));

  if (min < 10){ 
    min = "0" + min; 
  }
  if (sec < 10){ 
    sec  = "0" + sec;
  }

  return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use audio.duration(). It will give you result in seconds. You just have to change this in minutes and seconds. Demo of Code is here, hope it will help you.

```
song.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){

    var duration = song.duration; //song is object of audio.  song= new Audio();

    var sec= new Number();
    var min= new Number();
     sec = Math.floor( duration );    
     min = Math.floor( sec / 60 );
    min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;    
    sec = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
    sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;

    $("#total_duration").html(min + ":"+ sec);   //Id where i have to print the total duration of song.

    });
```

This code will definitely work for total duration. To get current Time, you just have to use `song.currentTime;` in place of `song.duration;`
Whole code will remain same.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. This is the only answer that worked for me :)

Comment: @anuj-sharma can you pls help me with this one  --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765496/how-to-dynamically-display-the-video-timestamp-in-html5-js

Answer (score 5):

ES6

```
       const audio = new Audio();
       audio.src = document.querySelector('#audio').src;
       audio.play();
       audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
            const currentTime = Math.floor(audio.currentTime);
            const duration = Math.floor(audio.duration);
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

for those who are looking to implement timeupdate in your jquery.

```
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src='test.mp3' type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

$("audio#myAudio").get(0).addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
        // do your stuff here
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  this.player = new Audio(item.url)
  this.player.play()

  this.player.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
      const currentTime = Math.floor(this.player.currentTime);
      const duration = Math.floor(this.player.duration);
      this.barWidth = (currentTime*100)/duration
  }, false);
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Was looking for an answer that was js only, and did not utilize the dom. thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

On TypeScript:

```
formatTime(seconds: number): string {

    let minutes: any = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    let secs: any = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = '0' + secs;
    }

    return minutes +  ':' + secs;
}
```

Remember to replace magic numbers with constants. It's an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not a new answer but a mix of multiple answers. You may try this.

```
<audio controls src="source_of_audio_file" id="audio" class="audio" ontimeupdate="update_time(this.currentTime, this.duration);" >
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>


function update_time(current_time, audio_duration){
  $("#currentAudioTime").html(format_time(current_time));
  $("#totalAudioDuration").html(format_time(audio_duration));
}

function format_time(audio_duration){
  sec = Math.floor( audio_duration );
  min = Math.floor( sec / 60 );
  min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;
  sec = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
  sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;
  return min + ":"+ sec;
}

<div>
  <span id="currentAudioTime"></span> : <span id="totalAudioDuration"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the [controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-controls)

> the user to control audio playback, including volume, **seeking**, and pause/resume playback.

```html
<audio controls>
<source src="data:audio/wav;base64,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">
</audio>
```

Answer (score -1):

to find the length of a audio file is simple!:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls="" id="audio">
        <source src="audio.mp3">
    </audio>
    <button id="button">
    <p id="p"></p>
        GET LENGTH OF AUDIO
    </button>
<script>
    var MYAUDIO = document.getElementById(audio);
    var MYBUTTON = document.getElementById(button);
    var PARA = document.getElementById(p);
    function getAudioLength() {
        PARA.innerHTML = duration.MYAUDIO
    }
MYBUTTON.addEventListener(click, getAudioLength);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```