# Is there any plugin for JavaScript/jQuery that allows me to trigger an action when a playing song reaches a certain play time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, media

I need a plugin for JavaScript/jQuery that handles playing audio, but I also need to be able to make my code trigger when it gets to a certain duration (eg. when the song hits 1:06, it displays an alert).

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried the `.setTimeout()` function?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Part of the reason may be that you need to consider all the variations -- what if the user scrubs the playback through 1:06? What if he skips ahead of it? What if the music is paused for thirty seconds before reaching that point?

Comment: This might answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993097/html5-display-audio-currenttime

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Just thought of that now.

Comment: @Blazemonger The audio will be playing in the background, no controls.

Comment: Background music with no controls for the user to pause or skip? Shame on you. There's a reason we let MySpace die a slow and painful death.

Comment: +1 @Blazemonger. I personally never used MySpace but I'm still laughing.

Comment: I needed it to be that way because it was a sort of animation type thing, interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but its worth taking a look...http://popcornjs.org/