# HTML5 audio tag Duration

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How come each time I call the

```
var track_length = $(".audio-player")[counter].duration;
```

it returns me this

```
351.234
```

How can I convert it to this type ofr Format minutes/seconds. 3:51 seconds ?(I am not sure if I am correct with my estimation of the time)

Comment: If the duration is 351 seconds, that's not the same as 3 minutes 51 seconds...

Comment: you might want to check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993097/html5-display-audio-currenttime

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean you want to convert it to min and secs, if yes then:

```
function readableDuration(seconds) {
    sec = Math.floor( seconds );    
    min = Math.floor( sec / 60 );
    min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;    
    sec = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
    sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;    
    return min + ':' + sec;
}
console.log( readableDuration(351.234) ); // 05:51
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js to do it:

```
moment.utc(this.duration * 1000).format("mm:ss");
```

The result will be "06:51".

```
moment.utc(this.duration * 1000).format("mm:ss.SSS");
```

The result will be "06:51.234".