# How to get the played time from HTML5 audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Consider a simple `HTML5 audio player as ([live example](https://jsfiddle.net/ewr150ax/1/))

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/flac.flac" type="audio/flac">
</audio>
<br />
<dic class="capture">
  Click here to get the current played time (elapsed time)
</dic>
```

Can we create a javascript event to catch the elapsed time of the playing audio by clicking on an HTML element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 display audio currentTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993097/html5-display-audio-currenttime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) to get the current timestamp, e.g.:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio-element");

document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(audio.currentTime);
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio-element" controls>
  <source src="https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/flac.flac" type="audio/flac">
</audio>
<br />
<button id="capture">
  Click here to get the current played time
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe HTML audio has a built in currentTime property that you could use to get the point in the audio where you're currently at:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Is this what you're looking for?