# Get played time from html5 player and send to Django function

Tags: javascript, django, html, html5-video

I am trying to get played time from HTML 5 video player.

I successfully get start and end time of first played time range.

I would like to send time range to function in Django 2.0 every time when user will start and stop video.

Any idea how to fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="videoPlayer" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="https://r1---sn-8xjug5oxu-f5fe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&key=yt6&fvip=6&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ip=109.197.67.187&ipbits=0&expire=1548168440&lmt=1472784021038997&pl=23&signature=DDDF5812EBA03434A7A729EC800B56146CC05041.C7FA04CAD5D8A50FF75AA9E1F73C0C372DAC83&dur=10393.901&ei=mNhGXIOJFo2V7QT6oKrYAw&source=youtube&itag=22&ratebypass=yes&mt=1548146723&mv=m&ms=au%2Crdu&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-8xjug5oxu-f5fe%2Csn-f5f7ln7y&id=o-AF-Y-B2o5xYN4x7hMQGhb9cRO7GCMR6bS0U818w8BuKV&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1621250&c=WEB" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        var vid = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
        var start_pl = vid.played.start(0);
        var end_pl = vid.played.end(0);
        document.getElementById("start_pl").innerHTML = start_pl;
        document.getElementById("end_pl").innerHTML = end_pl;
      }, 400);
</script>

start: <div id="start_pl"></div>
end: <div id="end_pl"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Thank You for any help!

https://jsfiddle.net/7vfpazsw/

Comment: use ajax to send your data to a django view.

Comment: Im newbie JS. Im not sure if provided script will catch every time range with setInterval function.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993097/html5-display-audio-currenttime