# How do you add the current time / total time to custom audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, current-time

I am trying to add a current time / total time element. Something that would look like 01:11/03:00. So far I have the progress bar and play pause button. These are my variables:

```
var music = document.getElementById('audioPlayer'); // id for audio element
var duration; // Duration of audio clip
var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton'); // play button
var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline

// timeline width adjusted for playhead
var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;
```

This is my audio player elements:

```
  <audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
        <source src="oh-my.mp3">      
    </audio>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--Audio Player Interface-->
        <div id="audioplayer">
            <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
            <div id="timeline">
                <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
                <div id="playhead"></div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tunechest000/1cgs9ewy/4/).

Comment: Maybe this can help ? [display audio currentTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993097/html5-display-audio-currenttime)

Comment: I was unable to find my answer there, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, I have added:
`<span id="tracktime">0:00 / 0:00</span>`
in the `<div id="audioplayer">` element (interface).

I have also replaced the `ontimeupdate` function of the `<audio>` element with:
`ontimeupdate="updateTracktime()"`
where the function `updateTracktime()` is defined like below:

```js
function updateTracktime(){
  let audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
  var counter = Math.round(Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime)/60)+":"+Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime-Math.round(Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime)/60))+"/"+Math.round(Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration)/60)+":"+Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration-Math.round(Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration)/60));
  document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = counter;
 }
```

And it seems to display something like you want? I've just used the answer in the post I've suggested but you can use your variables and your elements instead?

Comment: thanks you this worked though would you be able to answer my most recent question also?