# How do I link my seek slider with the audio player in HTML?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension that involves multiple audio players. I currently have play buttons that work for each individual audio, and I have also made the dummy version of a seek slider. I would like to link the audio with the slider so that I can control the progress of the audio and also see the time. Here is what I have now:

**popup.js**

```
const manageAudio = (audio) => {
  const playButton = audio.nextElementSibling;
  let isPlaying = false;
  audio.onplaying = function () {
    isPlaying = true;
  };
  audio.onpause = function () {
    isPlaying = false;
  };
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
  })
  $(playButton).click(function () {
    $(playButton).toggleClass("paused");
  });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (const audio of $('audio')) {
    manageAudio(audio);
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<audio src=".../...mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div class="play"></div>
<div class="controls">
    <input type="range" value="0" class="slider">
    <p>0:00</p>
    <p class="endtime">3:25</p>
</div>
```

The page looks like this:

[image: what the page looks like]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

### Recommendations:

set the min value for *range* `input` to 0;
do a check if an audio can be played by checking `oncanplay` (find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event));

##### Steps to be taken to at least reach some point

1. get the tracktime (in seconds);
2. set the maximun value for a *range* `input` to the **total** tracktime (`duration` - in seconds);
3. then using `ontimeupdate` you can get either a current playing time or set the slider's value (for more info please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993619);
4. to update the slider you can get the current time (`currentTime`) of a track and set this value to the *range* `input`.

So, you just need to track update events on slider and audio, and after any of these changes, you will take action to update one or another source.

```
audio.currentTime = 30; // where audio is your audio object; 30 is 30th second of your track
```

Please let me know whether this is enough for you to continue

###### How to set audio position? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565178))